# NOLOCK with Linq to SQL without setting Transaction IsolationLevel

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactionscope

Is there a way to use NOLOCK on a LIN2SQL single query without setting the Transaction IsolationLevel? I need to do this as the query part of a larger (distributed) transaction.

For example:

```
using (var txn = new TransactionScope())
{

    // query1
    // query2
    // query3
}
```

I want the changes of query 1 and 3 to be transactional, but I need NOLOCK on query2, which happens to be on a separate db to the other queries. If I re-set the transaction scope for query2 to ReadUncommitted then I get the error:

`The transaction specified for TransactionScope has a different IsolationLevel than the value requested for the scope.
Parameter name: transactionOptions.IsolationLevel`

Answer (score 5):

Will it work for you?

```
 using (var txn = new TransactionScope())
 {

    // query1
     using (TransactionScope txn2 = 
     new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew),
     new TransactionOptions() {//isolation level,timeout, etc}
     )
     {
    // query2
      }
    // query3
  }
```

Comment: This is effectively the issue, albeit lacking an explanation. The issue is you cannot change the IsolationLevel when using an ambient transaction. By specifying RequiresNew, you will not "join" the outer transaction and try to change it's IsolationLevel. Instead it will create a new transaction with it's own IsolationLevel (of ReadUncommitted).

Answer (score 0):

How about making query2 a stored procedure, with nolock in the sql, and calling that from Linq2Sql?